# Write and read struct with dynamic arrays and gsl_vectors in C

Tags: c, serialization, gsl

I have an structure similar to:

```
typedef struct FOO {

  int m,n;
  int * am;
  gsl_vector * bn;

} foo;
```

To allocate this structures I do:

```
foo * bar; 
bar=foo_alloc ( 10, 10 );
```

Where

```
foo * foo_alloc ( int m, int n ) {
  foo * f = (foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo));

  f->m=m;
  f->n=n;
  f->am=(int*)calloc(m,sizeof(int));
  f->bn=gsl_vector_calloc(n);
  return f;
}
```

I wish to write bar in a binary file and then read it again... How can I do this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

To be more specific, I tried with

```
fwrite(&bar,sizeof(*bar),1,file)
```

but `sizeof(*bar)` didn't work and by Google search I found that `sizeof` don't work with this kind of structures with dynamic arrays inside.

Is there a way to obtain the size of bar?

If not, I supouse I have to place an `fwrite` for each element, but in this case I don't know how to obtain the size of `gsl_vector` since this is also another structure with a dynamic array inside.

Comment: Er… `write` it into a (binary) file and `read` it again?… And don't tell me _your_ Google didn't tell you that…

Comment: Oh, and a serious comment: Do a search for endianness.

Comment: I tryed googling, but I found the things confusing. Since I am not a C programer, I wish to double check before trust in my self understanding of the google results.

Comment: And now? The code you've posted seems to be correct; the only question you've asked is answered with “look at `write` and `read`”. If something of the solutions you've found in the web is confusing, then tell us what's confusing. Sorry, but I can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: “but sizeof(*bar) didn't work”—what does that mean? In which way it didn't work?

Comment: Well, since sizeof(*bar) give me a very small size I suppose it was not working. From the @ooga answer I understand now that sizeof(*bar) count the size of the pointers inside the structure and the size of the corresponding dynamic arrays have to be separately measured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(*bar)` is correct. It's `&bar` that's wrong. Since `bar` is a pointer, you shouldn't use the address-of operator.

Also, you've only attempted to write the struct and haven't written the dynamically-allocated array data. Actually, writing the struct is pointless since the addresses will not be valid when the data is read back. You should just write the sizes (`m` and `n`) and the array data. When you read it back you need to `malloc/calloc` the struct and array space again.

Here's a runnable example. I've replaced your `gsl_vector`s with `double` to make it easier for other people to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int m, n;
    int *am;
    double *bn;
} Foo;

void foo_write(Foo *f, FILE *file) {
    fwrite(&(f->m), sizeof(f->m), 1, file);
    fwrite(&(f->n), sizeof(f->n), 1, file);
    fwrite(f->am, sizeof(*(f->am)), f->m, file);
    fwrite(f->bn, sizeof(*(f->bn)), f->n, file);
}

Foo *foo_read(FILE *file) {
    Foo *f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
    fread(&(f->m), sizeof(f->m), 1, file);
    fread(&(f->n), sizeof(f->n), 1, file);
    f->am = malloc(f->m * sizeof(*(f->am)));
    f->bn = malloc(f->n * sizeof(*(f->bn)));
    fread(f->am, sizeof(*(f->am)), f->m, file);
    fread(f->bn, sizeof(*(f->bn)), f->n, file);
    return f;
}

Foo *foo_alloc(int m, int n) {
    Foo *f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
    f->m = m;
    f->n = n;
    f->am = calloc(f->m, sizeof(*(f->am)));
    f->bn = calloc(f->n, sizeof(*(f->bn)));
    return f;
}

void foo_print(Foo *f) {
    int i;
    printf("%d, %d\n", f->m, f->n);
    for (i = 0; i < f->m; ++i)
        printf("%d ", f->am[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    for (i = 0; i < f->n; ++i)
        printf("%.1f ", f->bn[i]);
}

void foo_free(Foo *f) {
    free(f->am);
    free(f->bn);
    free(f);
}

int main() {
    FILE *file; 
    Foo *bar;
    int i;

    bar = foo_alloc(5, 10);
    for (i = 0; i < bar->m; ++i)
        bar->am[i] = i;
    for (i = 0; i < bar->n; ++i)
        bar->bn[i] = i;


    file = fopen("foo.bin", "wb");
    foo_write(bar, file);
    fclose(file);

    foo_free(bar);

    file = fopen("foo.bin", "rb");
    bar = foo_read(file);
    fclose(file);

    foo_print(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

You may be able to write and read the `gsl_vector`s like this (assuming the vectors are independent, i.e., that they don't share data blocks):

```
void foo_write(Foo *f, FILE *file) {
    size_t i;
    fwrite(&(f->m), sizeof(f->m), 1, file);
    fwrite(&(f->n), sizeof(f->n), 1, file);
    fwrite(f->am, sizeof(*(f->am)), f->m, file);
    for (i = 0; i < f->n; ++i)
        gsl_vector_fwrite(file, &(f->bn[i]));
}

Foo *foo_read(FILE *file) {
    size_t i;
    Foo *f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
    fread(&(f->m), sizeof(f->m), 1, file);
    fread(&(f->n), sizeof(f->n), 1, file);
    f->am = malloc(f->m * sizeof(*(f->am)));
    f->bn = malloc(f->n * sizeof(*(f->bn)));
    fread(f->am, sizeof(*(f->am)), f->m, file);
    for (i = 0; i < f->n; ++i)
        gsl_vector_fread(file, &(f->bn[i]));
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice answer, the example also answer other questions that I even do. I tried your example with the gsl_vector and work well. However gsl_vector have other dynamic structures inside. Should I read gsl_vector bn as you do in foo_read? Why my success with `fread(f->bn, sizeof(*(f->bn)), f->n, file);`?

Comment: @alexis Looking at `gsl_vector`s, things are definitely more complicated. If all of the vectors are independent (each owns its own data block), then you could probably use `gsl_vector_fwrite` and `gsl_vector_fread` (see edit above). The simple fwrite may have worked because the memory with the data still existed, which will not generally be the case! If you wrote one program to save the data and a different program to read it, it definitely wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks ooga !! And thanks in particular for that last edit and comment, that really help me a lot.